# Java print integer in 4 rows and 4 columns in below format without using array

Tags: java

I am suppose to create a program that prints out following:

16 15 14 13

9 10 11 12

8 7 6 5

1 2 3 4

Hers's my current code:

```
public class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int n=16;
        int rows = 4;
        int cols = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(n+" ");
                n--;
            }
            if(i != rows) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as below

16 15 14 13

12 11 10 9

8 7 6 5

4 3 2 1

Can someone please help to figure out the solution for this one?

Comment: It would make sense to have a list of lists, and loop over them.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of when the numbers need to be printed in reverse in a boolean. Then use one of two loops depending on that boolean.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 16;
        final int rows = 4;
        final int cols = 4;
        boolean reverse = false;

        for (int r = 1; r <= rows; ++r) {
            if (reverse) {
                for (int c = n - cols + 1; c <= n; ++c) {
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
                }

                n -= cols;
             } else {
                for (int c = 1; c <= cols; ++c, --n) {
                    System.out.print(n + " ");
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
            reverse = !reverse;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (but most likely not the desired) solution to the problem as stated is this:

```
System.out.println("16 15 14 13");
System.out.println(" 9 10 11 12");
System.out.println(" 8  7  6  5");
System.out.println(" 1  2  3  4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class Ideone  {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int n=16;
        int rows = 4;
        int cols = 4;
        int flag = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(n -cols*flag +(2*j -1)*flag +" ");
                n--;
            }
            if(i != rows) {
                System.out.println();
                flag = 1 - flag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a compilation problem. Edit your answer

Comment: replace the conditional statement with if else. `System.out.println();
                if(flag==0) {
                 flag = 1;
                } else{
                 flag =0;
                }`.  Edit your answer.

Comment: Or even easier: `flag = 1 - flag;`

Answer (score 0):

You could change the outer loop so it iterates `row/2` times and have two inner loops, one doing a forward iteration and one backward.